# json-schema passes validation if an array is passed instead of an object

Tags: javascript, jsonschema

This is my schema which manage profile in our application :

```
var ProfileJsonSchema = {
  properties: {
    Profiles: {
      optional: false,
      items: {
        optional: false,
        properties: {
          Email: {type: String},
          FirstName: {type: String},
          Zip: {type: String},
          City: {type: String}
}}}};
```

and my data

```
[{}]
```

and the code to test

```
validation = Validate([{}], ProfileJsonSchema);     
if (!validation.valid) {
  return;
}
// do something...
```

Well the validation is ok.
Why ?
Is there a solution to handle this type of error?

Comment: What JSON Schema Implementation did you choose? Can you provide a JSFiddle example? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have done some tests with the CommonJs version and the latest  kriszyp version (https://github.com/kriszyp/json-schema). I'm not good enough to put a standalone script on jsfiddle :(

Answer (score 0):

There's maybe a typo here:

```
validation = Validate([{}], , ProfileJsonSchema);
```

3 parameters instead of 2?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this a decade late, the json schema `type` assertion in missing. In the absence of this, any type is valid. The `properties` assertion may seem like it would only allow objects, but actually, it only asserts that `if a property Profiles exists then it must satisfy the declared subschema`. Since `Profiles` isn't even a required property, any object that does not have a `Profiles` property is also valid.